# global name 'tkagg' is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I know it is a common problem and I have read all the links related to this error. I realized I have to put matplotlib.use() before pyplot and etc. imports but still it does not work. I am working with jupyter notebook and python 2.7.These are all I have imported:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import*
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from collections import Counter
try: 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk as PlotNav
except: 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2TkAgg as PlotNav
```

and this the function that used `tkagg` in it to provide a navigation toolbar:

```
def monthly_sells(array,hh): 
        monse = tk.Toplevel(hh)
        array['monthj'] = pd.to_numeric(array['monthj'])
        x=array['monthj'].values.tolist()
        x.sort(key=int)
        f = Figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi=80)
        f.add_axes([0.2, 0.15,0.78,0.7])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=monse)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=6)
        tkagg.PlotNav(canvas, monse)

        p = f.gca()
        bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
        p.hist(x,bins,rwidth=0.8, label='sales amount in different months of year' )
        p.set_xlabel('month', fontsize = 10)
        p.set_ylabel('number of orders', fontsize = 10)
```

This error occurs when I click on the button that uses monthly_sells function as command.

> global name 'tkagg' is not defined

Comment: I think you're missing a `import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg`.

Comment: No. The line `tkagg.PlotNav(canvas, monse)` should probably read `PlotNav(canvas, monse)` because there is no `tkagg` defined (as the error says).

Comment: @rassar I imported that as well right after importing counter and now I get this error 'module' object has no attribute 'PlotNav'